# How to find the mean and standard deviation of rows in dataframes with some having NAs and others not

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to find the mean and standard deviation for C and P separately.

I have toyed around with this so far:

```
C <- rowMeans(dplyr::select(total, C1:41), na.rm=TRUE)
```

This didn't yield what I needed it to.

Then I thought about just using the summary, but again it didn't give me what I needed.

So then I thought of using na.omit:

Of course though, this would take out all of the data since I have NAs throughout the dataframe.

What am I missing here? Is this a matter of aggregating my data into certain groups?

I know describeby could force these descriptives, but again I'm not sure how to do that.

So, I think the angle I want to take is to order these, then aggregate and find totals, and then find the descriptives using describeby in order to avoid NAs. I'm stuck though. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'd reshape the whole data into a longer format, creating a new column called "person", having two values: "Adult" and "Child". The number of rows will be the same after deleting whole rows with NA and the number of columns halved

Comment: And use `dput` to provide a sample of your data. Don't just copy and paste the output from the console. What you've provided isn't easily usable.

Comment: What's wrong with `rowMeans(select(child_parent_total, SCAREDP1:SCAREDP41), na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: @Edward thank you for the tip on making data more useable. I'm never sure with how to share reproducible examples. Right now I have reshaped the data and have attempted to get the means using long form. rowmeans gives me a large table of values as opposed to just the means. It appears like a head with NA's included says "reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 128 entries. I'm not sure if this is what I want. I'm looking for the mean of the data which I expect to be one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
library(dplyr)

total %>%
  #Select only columns that have S in their name
  #i.e SP and SC
  select(starts_with('S')) %>%
  #Get the data in long format, remove NA values
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  #Create a group for each participant
  group_by(grp = c('Participant1', 'Participant2')[grepl('C\\d+', name) + 1]) %>%
  #Take mean and standard deviation for each group
  summarise(mean = mean(value), sd = sd(value))
```

Comment: @AlexSmith I guess you don't want to select `scared_pd_res` though. So use `select (matches('SCARED(C|P)\\d+'))` in second line and check.